# Python3 multiprocessing join can not wait

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am implementing a program for feature selection in large academic documents. The first step is to read each file, generate grams and do some pre-computation. I used multiprocessing.pool to make program run faster. Here is my codes of this part:

```
#number of process
processNum = 4
pool_precompute = mp.Pool(processes = processNum)

fileNum = len(filelist)
offset = fileNum // processNum

ProcessList = []
for i in range(processNum):
    if (i == processNum - 1):
        start = i * offset
        end = fileNum
    else:
        start = i * offset
        end = start + offset

    #call the function
    print (start, end, i)
    ProcessList.append(pool_precompute.apply_async(get_kgrams_df_pmi, args = (start, end, filelist, i)))
    #pool_precompute.apply_async(get_kgrams_df_pmi, args = (start, end, filelist, i))

pool_precompute.close()
pool_precompute.join()
```

My program must wait all the created processes to finish and then go on to the next steps. However, although I used join(), my program can not hang on at all, it seems that the join() function does not have any effect. Note that each process handle some amount of the file, they do not need to communicate with each other and they do not share any variables, there is a return value of get_kgrams_df_pmi, it is an integer computed in the function (the number of words in the document corpus). I would appreciate if anyone can find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just because that there is errors in my function called by the multiprocess pool, they stopped and did not print error information.